# Creating a new folder for Images uploading in Magento admin panel

Tags: magento2.2.6, popup

Currently, we are using the version Magento 2.2.6. We would like to create a new folder for the images with the admin panel as per the below image.

[image]

But the popup for creating a new folder hides behind the page-wrapper which is in the screenshot.

The popup is only displaying when we close the page wrapper.

I have tried to make this work by using CSS but with no success.

Could anyone please help me to get this work?

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: What happens when you click on **`Create Folder...`** button? Do you see any JS related error in the browser's console?

Comment: No, I haven't got the JS error. When I click the create folder button, the popup for creating a new folder is hiding behind the page.

Comment: It may be due to some custom CSS or JS overriding default Magento's CSS. I have checked it in Magento versions **`2.2.5`** and **`2.2.7`**. Both are working fine. I don't have 2.2.6 currently.

Comment: Yes, you're right. When I have checked about the cause of the error, I have found that there is a CSS that conflict in rendering the popup. Below is that CSS: 

.modal-slide.magento._show {
    z-index: 12000 !important;

But when I look about this CSS, I can't find the file. If you have known, please let me know the path of the CSS which contain the above said one.

Comment: I think this is coming from some LESS files. So you need to first search for all occurrences of **`.modal-slide`** in all LESS files. Then find the rest of the part manually of your CSS class where the first part matches.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I have found the CSS which is conflicting our design.

Comment: Glad that I could help. :)